# Facebook Instal Tracking like Google AdWords in iOS

Tags: ios, facebook, google-analytics

One of my clients asked me to add the conversion tracking of Google Analytics AdWords, and they send me this link:

https://developers.google.com/app-conversion-tracking/ios/conversion-tracking-server

We use Google Analytics to track everything in our app and we are not interested in use the Facebook SDK to track the same (or almost the same) we track on Google Analytics, so I have been looking for a way to use the Facebook Pixel in a similar way Google does.

In Google I just have to call this URL (this is the example of the link above):

> https://www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion/0123456789/?label=abCDEFG12hIJk3Lm4nO&rdid=8880ea97-db86-4e10-a10f-4e71461ab8f9&bundleid=com.example.MyApp&idtype=idfa&lat=0

If I get a 400 response the URL is not well formed and if I get a 200 response everything is ok, is pretty easy and in accordance with our development.

Is there a way to do something similar with the Facebook Pixel? I have look a lot on the web and everything I can find tells me to install the Facebook SDK in my iOS project.

Thanks to all in advance for the help.